# Which FTPserver supports a large number of clients

Tags: filesystems, lan, ftp-server

I have a practice room with a LAN. It is common for student to do exercises. A student create some files on a computer and I want:
- He/She can't see files of others.
- He/She can continue to work on his/her files.

I think this suits to a FTP server. But which fpt server can support over 3000 clients?
Or is there an alternative for this problem?
Thanks.